# Resamples (folds) for cross-validation in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, tidymodels

I'm using tidymodels framework for creating stratified resample folds for cross-validation in a random forest model. Is it possible to actually access and view / plot the data within each of these folds? Reproducible code below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

df_cv <- vfold_cv(iris, v = 10, strata =Species)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `vfold_cv` is an `rsplit` object. You can run `split1 <- get_rsplit(df_cv, index = 1)` to get the split. `analysis(split1)` will give you the analysis data frame and `assessment(split1)` will get you the assessment data frame.

You can also run `tidy(split1)` to get information about which rows went to the analysis set vs. which rows went to the assessment set.

[This reference](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/tidy.rsplit.html) gives a little bit more information about what you do with an `rsplit` object.

For a more in-depth understanding of the `rsplit` class, you can check out the code [here](https://github.com/tidymodels/rsample/blob/main/R/rsplit.R).